# How can I add a cordova plugin to a phonegap based project?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I've created a phonegap project, with the CLI :

```
phonegap create Projectname
```

This works fine and I can start it without problems. Now I want to add this Barcodescanner : https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner . I did this some time ago in my cordova based project like this:

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

Now I tried this with my Phonegap based project and it's obviously not working. But I've tried

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

too, which is not working too... Now is there one more possibility to add plugins, and thats plugman, but I don't get the plugman syntax at all ... Could you tell me at first why the phonegap command is not working and how to add the plugin with plugman. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the version from wildabeast is not compactible for phonegap version >3.2

Try adding this barcode scanner plugin,its specific to phonegap https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner

Install it using the syntax

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner
```

To get it to work I created a new project and copied my www to it and installed the plugin.It did not work for me in the old project.It might for you Iam not sure,just check

Comment: I'm getting the same error for this : 'Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project' . I think that happens because I've created the project with phonegap create..

Comment: Try building project as android and the install plugin.Make sure that you are inside the project folder while installing plugin.If it still doent work your only option is to install it manually

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding it manually? Just copy the Java sources to the src folder, the JavaScript (if any) to the assets folder, then manualy add a plugin element in the `/res/xml/config file`. Make sure to add permissions (like camera, file access, etc) to the manifest if needed.